# Richardson extrapolation formula for Runge-Kutta method

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, extrapolation

We use the 4-stage Runge Kutta method and we have computed $y_{n+1}^{(h)}$ and $y_{n+2}^{(h / 2)}$, two approximations of $y\left(t_{n}+h\right).$ Develop a formula for the Richardson extrapolation by assuming that the local truncation error is $C_{n} h^{5}$.

Comment: Yes, you apply the Richardson extrapolation formula. You need to be clear if $y^{(h)}_n$ and $y^{(h/2)}_{2n}$ are two separate RK4 iterations from which you compute an improved sequence, or if you restart both methods at each step from the extrapolation result. Then I would write the intermediary values as $y^{(h)}_{n,1}$ and $y^{(h/2)}_{n,2}$ to avoid a mix-up with the first interpretation.

Comment: To clarify, in my first comment I meant if these were for the first variant separate global RK4 iterations starting from $y_0$ and proceeding independently over the time interval, where then the Richardson extrapolation is post-processing. Or in the second variant (which I assume is the case in my answer), $y^{(h/k)}_{n,j}$, $k=1,2$, $j=0,1,...,k$, are short local iterations that start both at $y_n$, and $y_{n+1}$ is the value obtained from the Richardson extrapolation.

Comment: Yes, now I understand what you are saying, then I confirm that the second variant is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the same value $y_n$, performing $k$ steps with step size $h/k$ results in an approximation for the exact next value $y_{n+1}^*=y(t_{n+1};t_n,y_n)$ (exact solution to the IVP at $(t_n,y_n)$) with leading error term of the RK4 method according to
$$
y^{(h/k)}_{n,k}=y_{n+1}^*+kC(t_n)(h/k)^5+O(h^6)
$$
Comparing the results for $k=1$ and $k=2$ one gets approximations of the Richardson extrapolation
$$
y_{n+1}^*=\frac{16y^{(h/2)}_{n,2}-y^{(h)}_{n,1}}{16-1}+O(h^6)
$$
and the error estimate
$$
y^{(h)}_{n,1}-y_{n+1}^*=\frac{16}{15}\left(y^{(h)}_{n,1}-y^{(h/2)}_{n,2}\right),
$$
that is, at first the more precise value stands for the exact value, and then the difference is slightly corrected to get a better error estimate.

Comment: That is just solving the linear system to eliminate the term with $C(t_n)$, $$k^4(y^{(h/k)}_{n,k}-y^*_{n+1})+O(h^6)=C(t_n)h^5.$$ As the right side is independent of $k$, one can set the left sides equal for different $k$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, after writing the comment I thought and I found exactly that linear system.